# Java jpcap opendevice error, setRoutingOption

Tags: java, device, jpcap

I was messing a lot around with networking and raw sockets. I installed Jpcap and I tried some example code. When I tried the code to send a message with UDP, I got some errors with opening a device.
First, the devices are getting stored.

`NetworkInterface[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();`

Next the first device is tried to open, and that is the line of the error.

`JpcapSender sender=JpcapSender.openDevice(devices[0]);`

This is the error I got:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: setRoutingOption
     at jpcap.JpcapSender.nativeOpenDevice(Native Method)
     at jpcap.JpcapSender.openDevice(JpcapSender.java:38)
     at Test.main(Test.java:15)
 Exception in thread "main"
```

I have been looking around, but I could not find a solution that worked for me, 
hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest version of Jpcap 0.7 :

http://jpcap.gitspot.com/jpcap-0.7.zip